# When $ax - y(x-a) = b$ is an integer?

Tags: calculus

In the below expression $a$ and $b$ are big positive integers and $x$ and $y$ are positive integers whose value I want to find.

$$ax - y(x-a) = b$$

Also, I am not sure that I am allowed to enforce the next rule but can I say that there is only one integer solution for which $x$ and $y$ are positive? If I am allowed to say it then consider it as part of the definition.

When $x$ and $y$ are integers?

I run into this problem as part of my chat app development where I need to do some users calculations

Answer (score 0):

$$  (x-a)(y-a) = a^2 - b.   $$

---

IF  $a^2 - b > 0:$

Every factoring $$  0 < g \leq h $$ and
$$   gh = a^2 - b $$
leads to several pairs $(x,y)$

$$  x-a = g, \; \; \; y-a = h,  $$
$$  x-a = -g, \; \; \; y-a = -h,  $$
$$  x-a = h, \; \; \; y-a = g,  $$
$$  x-a = -h, \; \; \; y-a = -g.  $$

---

IF  $a^2 - b < 0:$

Every factoring $$  0 < g \leq h $$ and
$$   gh = b - a^2  $$
leads to several pairs $(x,y)$

$$  x-a = g, \; \; \; y-a = -h,  $$
$$  x-a = -g, \; \; \; y-a = h,  $$
$$  x-a = h, \; \; \; y-a = -g,  $$
$$  x-a = -h, \; \; \; y-a = g.  $$

Comment: How did you got to: $  (x-a)(y-a) = a^2 - b.   $

Comment: @Ilya: Subract $a^2$ from both sides, multiply everything by $-1,$ and factor the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite like this $$y= {x-a\over ax-b}$$ so $$ax-b\mid x-a\Longrightarrow ax-b\mid a(x-a)$$
and since $$ax-b\mid ax-b\Longrightarrow ax-b\mid a(x-a)-(ax-b) = a^2+b$$
So $ax-b = d$ and thus $x ={b+d\over a}$ where $d $ divides $a^2+b$. But be careful, not all $x$ are necessary integer, you must eliminate some of them.